# Angular 2 directive's lifecycle hook (ngAfterContentInit) not working as described in documentation

Tags: angular, lifecycle

I'm trying to get element's offsetLeft, but I get incorrect value unless I use setTimeout.

Basically in the directive I have this:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.offsetLeft);
}
```

The documentation states this for ngAfterContentInit "Lifecycle hook that is called after a directive's content has been fully initialized.". But instead of returning 40px it returns 8px (not even sure where it gets that 8).

Any ideas why it isn't working? Is it because the root element of the directive is not considered part of the directive and only it's children are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.el.nativeElement.offsetLeft);
    });
}
```

This is because at the moment `ngAfterContentInit()` fires children are still not rendered - so you need to give angular time to do that.

Comment: it does, but it also looks very hacky

Comment: @yodalr, though it does look hacky - it actually is not. :) This is just the way angular works. Main point here is that you **have** to look at the content at a later point in time and generally speaking this is the simplest way to make sure you do. However, if your content is getting rendered depending on some long http request, i.e. long time after your parent component is rendered, then the only reliable way to choose proper point in time is to explicitly communicate to components in the content and ask them by similar means when they are ready.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't wish to use the timeout, use AfterViewChecked with this syntax:

```
start = true;
.....
ngAfterContentChecked() {
    if (this.start){
         console.log(this.el.nativeElement.offsetLeft);
    }
    this.start = false;
}
```

Comment: I think it is worth noting that this hook is getting called after every subsequent ngDoCheck() (as angular docs suggest: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). This means that it has to be just blazing fast otherwise it can create huge negative performance impact on UI.

Comment: I must disagree with you. You use it or not Angular will anyway run thou its lifecycle anyway. It's what you put inside that matters, if you set a havy subscribtion or calculation inside afterviewchecked, then yes, it's not a good idea. Besides, it's 'protected' by the condition. On the otherside, I am very septic with evrything that is managed with a timeout

Comment: I didn't get what you're disagree with - this is essentially what I'm saying. :) I meant two things here: a) this handler must be very light - as you agreed - since it is called a lot, and "measuring" DOM element sometimes can be relatively heavy operation; b) it fires more than one time (much more actually!) which could be not what OP wanted (that's for them to figure out). That's what I wanted to say, maybe I did not express it very clear, sorry for that. As for timeout - I'm not fond of timeouts either but sometimes we have to use such things because we don't have something better...

Comment: My main concern is potential performance impact. I'd note it in the answer to warn others that it can be serious issue with this lifecycle hook.

Comment: No, if you set the condition, as it's done in the post, there is no significant impact

Comment: correct. But if you don't set such a condition then it will strike. And I'm sure that someone will do it and then will be wondering - why is it working so slow?..